# How to add text to TextView from Loader

Tags: java, android, classloader, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

Now I'm studying `Threads` and my task is to make a counter, which will add number from 0 to 9 to `TextView` with the help of `Loader`. Of course, I know that it isn't the best variant to use `Loader` for such tasks, but I'd like to understand how does it work.

So, I have the following code:

```
package asus.example.com.exercise4;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView counter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_threads);
        Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        Button cancelButton = findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
        counter = findViewById(R.id.counter);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.start_button:
                    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, new LoaderClass());
                    break;
                case R.id.cancel_button:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };



    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class AsyncTaskLoaderClass extends AsyncTaskLoader<Void>{

        AsyncTaskLoaderClass(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Void loadInBackground() {
            for (int i = 0; i<10;i++){
                counter.setText(i);
                SystemClock.sleep(500);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class LoaderClass implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Void>{

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Loader<Void> onCreateLoader(int i, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            return new LoaderActivity.AsyncTaskLoaderClass(LoaderActivity.this);
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Void> loader, Void aVoid) {
            counter.setText("Done!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Void> loader) {

        }
    }



}
```

When I run the project I have a runtime error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object returned from onCreateLoader must not be a non-static inner member class: AsyncTaskLoaderClass{eed39bf id=0}
```

Yes, I understand, that it means that `AsyncTaskLoaderClass` should be in another file or static, but in such case I won't have an opportunity to add text to `textview`. So, how can I solve this problem?

**UPD**

I changed the code in clicking start button in such way:

```
case R.id.start_button:
                Loader loader = getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, LoaderActivity.this);
                loader.forceLoad();
                Log.i(TAG, "Button start clicked");
                break;
```

And now each time in the loop I have the following error:

```
E/e.com.exercise: Invalid ID 0x00000009.
E/EventBus: Could not dispatch event: class asus.example.com.exercise4.LoaderActivity$MyAsyncTaskLoader$ProgressEvent to subscribing class class asus.example.com.exercise4.LoaderActivity
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9
```

**UPD 2**

Finally fixed the problem in the following way:

**Was**

```
counter.setText(i);
```

**Now**

```
counter.setText(""+i);
```

Probably I don't understrand why it works, but it works

Comment: can u show me code of add textview in your xml file?

Comment: where is your textview id in Java file???

Comment: @Niceumang, updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the Activity implement LoaderCallbacks. Also a Loader retrieves ***one particular value*** in its `onLoadFinished` callback, and it should return the retrieved (loaded) item as a result.

To change what value is being loaded by a Loader, you're supposed to restart the loader with a new argument bundle, and pass in the parameters so that it knows what it is doing.

Then again, you are trying to create something like "publishProgress" in AsyncTask; Loaders cannot do that out of the box, and need some variant of "sending an event" (handler threads if you are adventurous, but most likely an [event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), see `implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'`).

TL;DR: use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for this.

```
public class LoaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Void> {
    private TextView counter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_threads);

        Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        Button cancelButton = findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        counter = findViewById(R.id.counter);
        startButton.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, LoaderActivity.this);
        });
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
            // do nothing, apparently
        });

        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onLoaderProgressEvent(MyAsyncTaskLoader.ProgressEvent event) {
        counter.setText("" + event.getNumber());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Void> onCreateLoader(int i, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        return new MyAsyncTaskLoader(LoaderActivity.this);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Void> loader, Void aVoid) {
        counter.setText("Done!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Void> loader) {

    }

    public static class MyAsyncTaskLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Void> {
        public static class ProgressEvent {
            private final int number;

            public ProgressEvent(int number) {
                this.number = number;
            }

            public int getNumber() { return number; }
        }

        public MyAsyncTaskLoader(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Void loadInBackground() {
            for (int i = 0; i<10;i++){
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new ProgressEvent(i));
                SystemClock.sleep(500);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried your code, but it still doen't work.I thought for some time and maybe I am wrong, but the problem can be caused because `public void onLoaderProgressEvent(MyAsyncTaskLoader.ProgressEvent event)` isn't used anywhere, or I didn't understand correct how does it should work

Comment: If you use the `EventBus.getDefault().register(this)` then EventBus will know how to find the Activity because it has a method annotated with `@Subscribe` and has an argument type of `ProgressEvent`

Comment: So, maybe I missed something (here's the code of my classes: https://pastebin.com/quUuZa5D) , but when I watched in debugger method `public Void loadInBackground()` isn't called at all

Comment: That is odd! However, maybe you can try calling `loader.forceLoad()`?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Ahhh I didn't notice that the int was set as a text resource, sorry :|

Answer (score 0):

Your are using inner `AsyncTaskLoaderClass` in `Activity` class. Inner class holds the reference of Outer class. That means your `AsyncTaskLoaderClass` may hold `Activity` reference in some cases. Make your inner class static.

You have 2 solutions. Make `AsyncTaskLoaderClass` a separate class file or make `AsyncTaskLoaderClass` a static class.

Answer (score -2):

make textview public static like this `public static TextView counter;`

Comment: No, don't do that.